# How to get Karma html reporter working in karma conf?

Tags: javascript, git, unit-testing, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

**How to get Karma html reporter working in karma conf?**

To run my unit tests I type: "**npm run test**" and the tests run fine in git bash.
But I want to see them in the reporter.html file.

I've made a reporter.html file next to the karma conf file in the root directory. The reporter.html file has nothing in it.

I think the reporter.html file gets populated when I run **npm run tests** and the reporter html page shows up. But this doesn't happen.

This is the link to the bit bucket repo: https://bitbucket.org/snproject/

**This is my karma conf:**

```
  module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({

      basePath: '',

      frameworks: ['jasmine'],

      files: [
        {pattern: 'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js', included: true, watched: true},
        {pattern: 'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.js', included: true, watched: true},
        {pattern: 'node_modules/angular2/bundles/testing.js', included: true, watched: true},
        {pattern: 'node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js', included: true, watched: true},
        {pattern: 'node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.js', included: true, watched: true},      
        {pattern: 'src/firebase/firebase.js', included: true, watched: true},  

        {pattern: 'karma-test-shim.js', included: true, watched: true},

        {pattern: 'src/**/*.js', included: false, watched: true},
        {pattern: 'src/**/*.html', included: false, watched: true},
        {pattern: 'src/**/*.css', included: false, watched: true},
        {pattern: 'src/**/*.ts', included: false, watched: false},
        {pattern: 'src/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false}
      ],

      proxies: {
        "/app/": "/base/src/app/"
      },

      reporters: ['progress', 'html'],

      //This doesnt seem to work or show up????
      htmlReporter: {
        outputFile: 'reporter.html'              
      },

      port: 9877,
      colors: true,
      logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
      autoWatch: true,
      browsers: ['Chrome'],
      singleRun: false
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you refer to the [karma-html-reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-html-reporter) page, you can see that `outputFile` is not one of the options the reporter gets.

Apparently, you don't get to decide about the name of the output file. You *can* decide where you want the results to be saved. By default, the reporter creates a folder named `karma_html`, in which for every browser/OS a folder is created with an `index.html` file, which contains the test results.

Looking at your repo, it looks like this folder was created (and you even committed it...), so everything works.

Comment: Hi yarons, so how do I see the results? Eg what's the url?

Comment: like I said, it should be in your file system, under `karma_html`. [Here it is in your repo](https://bitbucket.org/snproject/angular2-typescript-and-firebase-project/src/7b9901e83c0e347a9d6179d93bd1b7beeb3f2843/karma_html/Chrome%2047.0.2526%20(Windows%208.1%200.0.0)/index.html?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default)

Answer (score 1):

[karma-html-reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-html-reporter) generates results in 'outputDir' relative to working directory instead of relative to the 'basePath' of karma.conf.js

My problem was solved by using [kamra-htmlfile-reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-htmlfile-reporter) which correctly generated results at 'outputFile' path relative to the 'basePath'.